# mapstruct:1.4.0.CR1: error while using the "." as target property

Tags: java, mapstruct

As stated here [is target "." operator valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63934577/mapstruct-use-as-target-property-is-it-currently-supported) i tried to get the "." operator as target property working, but i get an error during the build process as follows under this configuration:

- Spring Boot 2.1.2 (but not important i think)
- Lombok 1.18.4
- MapStruct 1.4.0.CR1
- Java 1.8.0_92
- Intellij 2019.3 Ultimate (but not important i think)

Bank class

```
@Data
public class BankEntity {

    private CustomerEntity customer;
}
```

Customer class

```
@Data
public class CustomerEntity {

    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

CustomerDto class

```
@Data
public class CustomerDto {

    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

Mapper class

```
public interface CustomerMapper {

    @Mapping(target = ".", source = "bank.customer")
    CustomerDto toDto(BankEntity bank);

}
```

SIMPLE TestCase

```
    @Test
    public void bankToCustomerDtoTest() {
        BankEntity bank = new BankEntity();
        CustomerEntity customer = new CustomerEntity();
        customer.setId("123");
        customer.setName("Smith");
        bank.setCustomer(customer);
        CustomerMapper customerMapper = Mappers.getMapper(CustomerMapper.class);
        CustomerDto dto = customerMapper.toDto(bank);
        System.out.println(dto);
    }
```

Error:(7, 8) java: Internal error in the mapping processor: java.util.NoSuchElementException    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:854)     at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.util.Collections.first(Collections.java:50)    at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.BeanMappingMethod$Builder.handleDefinedMappings(BeanMappingMethod.java:477)      at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.model.BeanMappingMethod$Builder.build(BeanMappingMethod.java:184)      at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperCreationProcessor.getMappingMethods(MapperCreationProcessor.java:376)      at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperCreationProcessor.getMapper(MapperCreationProcessor.java:151)      at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperCreationProcessor.process(MapperCreationProcessor.java:122)    at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperCreationProcessor.process(MapperCreationProcessor.java:76)     at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.process(MappingProcessor.java:283)     at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.processMapperTypeElement(MappingProcessor.java:263)    at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.processMapperElements(MappingProcessor.java:221)   at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.process(MappingProcessor.java:156)     at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)     at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)   at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)    at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)     at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)     at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)   at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain.compile(JavacMain.java:207)    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compileJava(JavaBuilder.java:486)     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compile(JavaBuilder.java:338)     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.doBuild(JavaBuilder.java:263)     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:216)   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1328)      at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1006)     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1073)   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:967)     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:796)      at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:378)     at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:140)     at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:297)   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:130)    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:232)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: StackOverflow is not for reporting bugs. If you think that you have found a bug then please report it at https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a question, but rather a bug report.

Comment: Ok Filip. I agree. Was unsure If this is an error of my own or a bug...